# Give a specific user permissions to a device without giving access to other users

Tags: linux, permissions, block-device

I have a card reader attached on `/dev/sdb`.

What I do is giving all permissions to owner, group and the rest of the world, using:

```
sudo chmod 777 /dev/sdb
```

Can I just use another combination, allowing only the owner (me) to use the card reader?

There is only one user account.

Comment: Can you please run `ls -l /dev/sdb`. I am guessing that this is owned by root, but would be good to make sure.

Comment: It says: "brw-rw---- 1 root"

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There are multiple ways of accomplishing this.

### 1. Add your user to the group that owns the device

Generally in most distros, block devices are owned by a specific group. All you need to do is add your user to that group.

For example, on my system:

```
# ls -l /dev/sdb
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 16 2014/07/07-21:32:25 /dev/sdb
```

Thus I need to add my user to the `disk` group.

```
# usermod -a -G disk patrick
```

### 2. Change the permissions of the device

The idea is to create a udev rule to run a command when the device is detected.

First you need to find a way to identify the device. You use `udevadm` for this. For example:

```
# udevadm info -a -n /dev/sdb

Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.

  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block/sdb':
    KERNEL=="sdb"
    SUBSYSTEM=="block"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{ro}=="0"
    ATTR{size}=="31116288"
    ATTR{stat}=="     279      219     3984     1182        0        0        0        0        0      391     1182"
    ATTR{range}=="16"
    ATTR{discard_alignment}=="0"
    ATTR{events}=="media_change"
    ATTR{ext_range}=="256"
    ATTR{events_poll_msecs}=="-1"
    ATTR{alignment_offset}=="0"
    ATTR{inflight}=="       0        0"
    ATTR{removable}=="1"
    ATTR{capability}=="51"
    ATTR{events_async}==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0':
    KERNELS=="6:0:0:0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
    DRIVERS=="sd"
    ATTRS{rev}=="0207"
    ATTRS{type}=="0"
    ATTRS{scsi_level}=="0"
    ATTRS{model}=="STORAGE DEVICE  "
    ATTRS{state}=="running"
    ATTRS{queue_type}=="none"
    ATTRS{iodone_cnt}=="0x184"
    ATTRS{iorequest_cnt}=="0x184"
    ATTRS{device_busy}=="0"
    ATTRS{evt_capacity_change_reported}=="0"
    ATTRS{timeout}=="30"
    ATTRS{evt_media_change}=="0"
    ATTRS{max_sectors}=="240"
    ATTRS{ioerr_cnt}=="0x2"
    ATTRS{queue_depth}=="1"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="Generic "
    ATTRS{evt_soft_threshold_reached}=="0"
    ATTRS{device_blocked}=="0"
    ATTRS{evt_mode_parameter_change_reported}=="0"
    ATTRS{evt_lun_change_reported}=="0"
    ATTRS{evt_inquiry_change_reported}=="0"
    ATTRS{iocounterbits}=="32"
    ATTRS{eh_timeout}=="10"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/host6/target6:0:0':
    KERNELS=="target6:0:0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
    DRIVERS==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/host6':
    KERNELS=="host6"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
    DRIVERS==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0':
    KERNELS=="1-1.3:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb-storage"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="08"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="06"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="50"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="02"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3':
    KERNELS=="1-1.3"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1.3"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="05e3"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="5"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="500mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="80"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0207"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{serial}=="000000000207"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="1115"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Generic"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0727"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{product}=="USB Storage"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1':
    KERNELS=="1-1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="8087"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="6"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0000"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="61"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0024"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1':
    KERNELS=="usb1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="3"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0313"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:1d.0"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="26"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 3.13.6-gentoo ehci_hcd"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{product}=="EHCI Host Controller"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:1d.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="ehci-pci"
    ATTRS{irq}=="23"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x144d"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0320"
    ATTRS{companion}==""
    ATTRS{enabled}=="1"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="0f"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x1e26"
    ATTRS{uframe_periodic_max}=="100"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}==""
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-3"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0xc0d3"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

Then create a new file in `/etc/udev/rules.d`, such as `99-cardreader.rules`:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0727", ATTRS{serial}=="000000000207", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/chmod 777 /dev/$name"
```

Here I used the output from the `udevadm info` command to find some identifying information for the device. I used the `SUBSYSTEM="block"` entry for the very first entry, and then the `ATTRS` values from the 6th entry. This will basically find the USB device with that product & serial number, and then find the block device that results from that USB device.

The `RUN` command will change the permissions on the device to `777`. However I don't consider this a very good solution as this opens the device up to the world. Instead a better solution might be:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0727", ATTRS{serial}=="000000000207", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/setfacl -m u:patrick:rw- /dev/$name"
```

This will grant the user `patrick` read/write access to the device.

*Note:* It is important to remember that when writing udev rules, you can only use parameters from the top device, and one other device in the chain. Thus I can use the `SUBSYSTEM="block"` parameter, and the `ATTRS` parameters. But I could not use any parameters from any other device in the chain, or the rule would fail to match.

Comment: In systemd 219, at least, udev lets you use MODE="777" instead of RUN+="/bin/chmod 777 /dev/$name".  I don't believe it has an alternative to running setfacl explicitly, though.

Comment: what is `$name` in the written rule? should I replace it with `sdb`?

Comment: @Marecky https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/udev.html#%24name "The current name of the device. If not changed by a rule, it is the name of the kernel device.". You don't replace it with anything, you leave as is.

Comment: Thanks, I just applied your answer to my specific issue, which was insufficient rights for regular user to access raw hard disk configured as boot-disk for guest Windows 7 running in VirtalBox.

Comment: Should probably use "/usr/bin/env chmod" and "/usr/bin/env setfacl" so that they work even if they are in a different directory. (Although really, if you have chmod somewhere else you've likely got bigger problems... ;-))  Hey, at the very least maybe someone will learn about this technique for the first time. =)

Comment: Note that adding a user to the `disk` group is in most cases essentially equivalent to giving them root access, as they may freely craft any arbitrary setuid binary on any mounted filesystem located on any block device (in addition to simply being able to read/write anything at all on the filesystem, which likely provides a near-infinite number of privilege escalation points). I'd suggest option 2 as the more appropriate solution in almost all situations.