# VERR_ACCESS_DENIED when trying to add a raw disk to virtual box

Tags: permissions, virtualbox

I created a virtualbox raw disk pointing to a functioning, booting USB drive with a small linux distro on it.

```
sudo ./VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename ~/VirtualBox\ VMs/MyTinyLinux/rawdiskonusb.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/disk2 -partitions 2
```

When I try to add it to a virtualbox VM, I get this error:

```
Failed to open the disk image file ~/VirtualBox VMs/MyTinyLinux/rawdiskonusb.vmdk.

Permission problem accessing the file for the medium '~/VirtualBox VMs/MyTinyLinux/rawdiskonusb.vmdk' (VERR_ACCESS_DENIED).

Result Code: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80BB0004)
Component: MediumWrap
Interface: IMedium {4afe423b-43e0-e9d0-82e8-ceb307940dda}
Callee: IVirtualBox {0169423f-46b4-cde9-91af-1e9d5b6cd945}
Callee RC: VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80BB0001)
```

I saw that the raw disk vmdk file was owned by root.  I chown'ed it to my own user.

Still get the same error.   I suspect it would work if I ran virtualbox as root, but I really do not want to do that.  Is there anyway to make this work?

Comment: VirtualBox needs root access for a bunch of things, and you already use sudo so you might as well do a proper root startup to get proper environment and user properties.

Comment: That's probably related to the "method" you used to create the disk.  So, you're trying to access the USB disk, but the Error is referencing the previous image file location.

Comment: Same issue for me. When I try to execute as sudo, it does not allow x64 machines, that was my case, and then there is no solution for me... :'( - usind on linux

Answer (score 46):

User should be in a `disk` group to access raw partitions (as Gilles mentioned by last reference in his answer).

```
sudo usermod -a -G disk $USER
```

Comment: this works for me too - **note** that you are required to log out after adding yourself to the group, or this change will not be applied. That goes for any group modifications actually

Comment: Using only that command was sufficient for me

Comment: You have to logout/in to have group membership reevaluated. You can do `su - $USER` to reevaluate it for a single terminal. https://superuser.com/questions/272061/reload-a-linux-users-group-assignments-without-logging-out

Comment: As user you can also activate the new group by `newgrp disk; newgrp $USER` w/o logout.

Comment: What about on macOS, where `usermod` doesn't exist?

Comment: OK so for anyone on Mac, it's enough to chown the disk you're trying to access:
```
sudo chown ${USER} /dev/disk3
```

Answer (score 37):

The poster used linux on the host machine. If you came here and use **Windows** as a host (like me) there is an easy solution to this error. Windows doesn't allow raw disk access if you don't **start VirtualBox with administrator priviledges**.

Comment: This answer used to work for me when I used VirtualBox 5.x, but I just tried with VirtualBox 6.1.38 and it doesn't seem to be working any more.  Furthermore, with old versions of VirtualBox, when I started VirtualBox.exe as administrator it showed the VMs attached to the system's administrator account rather than my own user's, but now it shows my own VMs no matter how I start it.  I guess they've updated it to drop admin priveleges?

Answer (score 19):

from 2020 here:

1. run virtual box *service* as administrator (**VBoxSVC.exe**), if running kill it first.
2. run virtual box main executable (**VirtualBox.exe** whatever is on your desktop) as adminstrator too

Comment: This answer is a bit unclear, also it is for Windows, not Linux…

Comment: This a thousand times... The fact that it's for Windows is irrelevant. This is information you cannot find anywhere else. I tried every combination of offline-ing disks, double clearing readonly attributes just to be sure, running as admin, not running as admin, etc to no avail... Finally, a solution to this damn problem that creeps up on me randomly once a year. Running VBovSVC as admin/su is crucial when you are running virtual machines on a physical medium. Thank you kapo!

Comment: There is no need to start `VBoxSVC.exe` as Administrator. It's enough to kill it, if it wasn't started with elevated credentials. Then when you run `VBoxManage` or `VirtualBox` as Administrator, they will start `VBoxSVC.exe` automatically with the required integrity level.

Comment: @facetus - this used to work for me on older versions of virtualbox, but with 6.1.x I now find you do have to manually run VBoxSVC as suggested in the answer.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the version of VirtualBox, but there is something with your setup. `VBoxManage` and `VirtualBox` of course start `VBoxSVC.exe` automatically, how else it could have worked. I've been using VirtualBox since first releases, it always worked this way, and works now.

Answer (score 12):

Check the permission on *all* the files involved, including the directories: `~/VirtualBox VMs`, `~/VirtualBox VMs/MyTinyLinux`, `~/VirtualBox VMs/MyTinyLinux/rawdiskonusb.vmdk`, `/dev/disk2`. The directories need to be readable and traversable by your user (`chmod +rx`) and the image file and the raw disk need to be readable and writable (`chmod +rw`).

You'll need to allow your user to access the disk; since `/dev` is populated automatically at each boot, you'll need to add a udev to do this. See [Give a specific user permissions to a device without giving access to other users](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141255/give-a-specific-user-permissions-to-a-device-without-giving-access-to-other-user/141257#141257)

Answer (score 7):

Since there's no accepted answer, I'll post this as an answer for the moment.
In addition to ensuring you're in the right groups, as others have posted above:

```
sudo usermod -a -G disk $USER
sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers $USER
```

If you are still getting the `VERR_ACCESS_DENIED` error, you need to, as per the comment by @Cybex, **logout and log back in** for the above group additions to take effect.

Comment: "vboxusers" was not needed for my case, only "disk" (fedora29). On mint19, I could not run that VM with rawdisk, except using sudo.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the distribution, you might have to add your username to the VirtualBox group.

```
usermod -a -G vboxusers myusername
```

Additionally, according a similar Q&A on [askubunt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144780/virtual-box-wont-accept-iso-to-install-os), you might have a corrupt ISO.  In your case, I would guess it means a botched conversion to raw disk.  Try searching on how to correctly do that procedure and repeat it, in case the conversion got botched somehow during the first procedure.

---

If that's *still* not a solution, then follow the advice in the [VirtualBox Manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#rawdisk) and add the `-relative` option:

> Creating the image requires read/write access for the given device.
>   Read/write access is also later needed when using the image from a
>   virtual machine. If this is not feasible, there is a special variant
>   for raw partition access (currently only available on Linux hosts)
>   that avoids having to give the current user access to the entire disk.
>   To set up such an image, use
>
> VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename /path/to/file.vmdk
>         -rawdisk /dev/sda -partitions 1,5 -relative
>
> When used from a virtual machine, the image will then refer not to the
>   entire disk, but only to the individual partitions (in the example
>   /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda5). As a consequence, read/write access is only
>   required for the affected partitions, not for the entire disk. During
>   creation however, read-only access to the entire disk is required to
>   obtain the partitioning information.

Answer (score 3):

The problem (for me) was To show only file name without the entire directory path. ... Only filename is needed:

```
VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename rawdiskonusb.vmdk -rawdisk \\.\PhysicalDrive#
```

worked nicely.

Comment: this worked for me on windows with ubuntu VM -- for some reason when i was doing like  -filename C:\rawdisk it did not work, but -filename rawdisk does. It puts the file in the virtual box directory though (which is fine)

Answer (score 1):

For A Windows Host (my case) I found THE only solution was a simple reboot of the host machine.  Immediately attached without errors upon restart.

Comment: I had the same problem. Solved by rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but the issue was that I was running the sudo command while in finder I was in my home volume, I cd'd to Volume/Users/Owner where my profile is called owner and then it worked perfectly.