# Adding Raw Disk to a Virtual Box gives the following errors

Tags: linux, windows, disk

I am running Virtual Box on Linux Mint and when trying to add a rawdisk `.vmdk` to my virtual machine I get the following errors.

> Permission problem accessing the file for the medium
> '/home/stephen/VirtualBox VMs/Windows10/test.vmdk'
> (VERR_ACCESS_DENIED).
>
> Result Code:
>  VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80BB0004)
>  Component:
> MediumWrap
>  Interface:IMedium
> {ad47ad09-787b-44ab-b343-a082a3f2dfb1}
>  Callee: IVirtualBox
> {d0a0163f-e254-4e5b-a1f2-011cf991c38d}
>  Callee RC:
> VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80BB0001)

I created the raw VMDK using two different methods that I have read about, and each time I get that same error. Here they are

```
sudo VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename "/home/stephen/VirtualBox VMs/Windows10/test.vmdk" -rawdisk /dev/sda -partitions 3 -relative
```

and this

```
sudo VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename "/home/stephen/VirtualBox VMs/Windows10/Windows10_2.vmdk" -rawdisk /dev/sda3
```

I know they are pretty much the same, but I read that adding the partition and relative options enabled some people to fix that error.

I don't know if this changes much, but the raw disk I am trying to use is `sda3` and the box is being run on `sda2`.

Also, I have added my user to the disks group because that was another option that was suggested to fix this error. I am open for anything.

Comment: Is the virtualbox running instance running as root, as you, as a service account?   Becuase you used sudo to create the vmdk it's probably owned by root and only readable by root.  You may need to `chown` it to the correct user.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VERR\_ACCESS\_DENIED when trying to add a raw disk to virtual box](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/284704/verr-access-denied-when-trying-to-add-a-raw-disk-to-virtual-box)

Answer (score 2):

.vmdk for rawdisk access needs to be created with regular user access -> **not root**.

Not nice, not safe, but at least a working solution is to change permissions of blockdevice you are going to access with this .vmdk. ie. `sudo chmod 777 /dev/sdXX`.

Then you can easily create vmdk file for RawDisk access with this VirtualBox command:

```
VBoxManage createmedium disk --filename /path-to-file.vmdk --format=VMDK --variant RawDisk --property RawDrive=/dev/sdXX
```

I suppose there might be some problems with it between reboots depending on your hardware configuration.

Tested on:

Ubuntu 22.04

VirtualBox 7.04

Answer (score 0):

You didn't have to use `sudo` to create the said files - now they are owned by the root user and naturally VBox cannot use them because they are mode 644.

If you don't want to recreate them, you can simply:

```
sudo chown myuser:myuser /path/file.vmdk
```

Comment: simply changing file permissions of .vmdk created from RawDisk does not work.

Answer (score 0):

## Oracle VM VirtualBox - Adding raw disk/physical disk (or avoid "VERR_ACCESS_DENIED" error)

To avoid the "VERR_ACCESS_DENIED" error you need to put your device "/dev/sdX" (replace the X with the correct letter) under the ownership and permission of your user ("$USER"), as "/dev/sdX" is originally under the ownership of the "root" user.

**NOTE:** Oracle VM VirtualBox is run by your user, so it will be your user who must have the necessary access to the device "/dev/sdX".

### Adding raw disk/physical disk to Oracle VM VirtualBox

**MODEL**

```
sudo chown $USER "/dev/sdX"
sudo chown :$USER "/dev/sdX"
sudo chmod 700 "/dev/sdX"
VBoxManage createmedium disk --filename "<PATH_TO_VMDK>/dev_sdX_vmdk.vmdk" --format=VMDK --variant RawDisk --property RawDrive="/dev/sdX"
```

**Thanks!**