# VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND while trying to add raw hard disk in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have created a bootable usb and created a virtual box raw disk with the following command-

```
sudo VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename popliveusb.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/sdd1
```

But when I was adding raw disk to my virtual machine's storage, I was getting VERR_ACCESS_DENIED error. Then I followed [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/284704/verr-access-denied-when-trying-to-add-a-raw-disk-to-virtual-box) solution.
I changed the owner using this command `sudo chown eh54n:eh54n popliveusb.vmdk`.
Then added my user to `disk` group using this command `sudo usermod -a -G disk $USER`.

But now I am getting **VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND** error. This is the full error-

```
Failed to open the disk image file /home/eh54n/popliveusb.vmdk.

Could not find file for the medium '/home/eh54n/popliveusb.vmdk' (VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND).

Result Code: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80BB0004)
Component: MediumWrap
Interface: IMedium {ad47ad09-787b-44ab-b343-a082a3f2dfb1}
Callee: IVirtualBox {d0a0163f-e254-4e5b-a1f2-011cf991c38d}
Callee RC: VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80BB0001)
```

When I run the VirtualBox using sudo, I don't have my VMs. How can I add the vmdk raw disk to my VM?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was a rookie mistake. After creating the vmdk file I removed the usb stick. That's why the VM did not find the files. It was also mentioned in the VirtualBox [Manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#rawdisk).

> On a Linux host, to create an image that represents an entire physical hard disk which will not contain any actual data, as this will all be stored on the physical disk